# Express.js update/put route does not work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a website where I want to add, edit and delete student contact data. The data is stored in a SQLite database. My post, get and delete routes (Express API) work but my update route does not.
I load the data of an existing contact into a html form and my plan is to edit the data in the form to send the updated data via a button. But I get the error message "Cannot GET /api/update/contacts/1" although I've implemented a POST method request.
I guess the request doesn't hit the API endpoint but I don't know why, especially since all the other routes are working. Can anyone help?

I already tried MethodOverride, but it also did not work.

The code in my html page with the form and the button:

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
  <button
  onclick="update()"      
  id="aktualisierenButton"
        type="submit"
      >Aktualisieren
      </button> 

<script>
function update() {
 window.open("/api/update/contacts/" + localStorage.getItem("paraID"), 
    "_blank",
           "toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,width=800,height=800");
   window.close();
}
```

I already tried MethodOverride, but it also did not help.

The code in my start.js file where I handle the routes:

```
app.put("api/update/contacts/:studentID", async (request, response) => {
  const studentID = parseInt(request.params.studentID);
  const existingContact = await contactsManager.getContact(studentID);
  if (existingContact) {
    const contact = request.body;
    await contactsManager.updateContact(studentID, contact);
    response.status(200).send();
  } else {
    response.status(400).send({
      error: "The contact with the specified studentID does not exist.",
    });
  }
});
```

The code in my ContactsManager.js file where I handle the database requests:

```
async updateContact(studentID, contact) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.run(
        "UPDATE contacts SET vorname = ?, nachname = ?, mail = ?  WHERE studentID = ?",
        [contact.vorname, contact.nachname, contact.mail, studentID],
        (error, row) => {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          } else {
            resolve(row);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `window.open` will make a `GET` request to the resource and load it into a window.  Instead of creating a new window then destroying it just to update your data, try using the Fetch API instead.

Using the fetch api with a `PUT` request would look something like below.  You will need to adapt this to your specific data, and process or display the result if that's what you are trying to achieve by opening a new window, but this should give you a starting point.

```js
try {
  let fetchUrl = "https://mysite.url/api/update/contacts/" + localStorage.getItem("paraID")
  let fetchOptions = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json" // Update with your data type
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data: myData // Update with your JSON data to PUT
    })
  }
  let response = await fetch(fetchUrl, fetchOptions)
  if (response.ok) {
    // Convert the response to json and process
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Handle network errors here
  console.error(error)
}
```

Your endpoint also does not implement a `POST` request, it uses a `PUT` request.  If you wanted a `POST` request you should use `app.post` instead of `app.put`, although using a `PUT` request is fine for what you are trying to achieve.